# How to prove triangle inequality for this p- norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, normed-spaces, triangle-inequality

we define
$ l_p=\{x=(x_n) : \sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_n|^p < \infty\} (p\in [1,\infty) ) $

I tried to prove that
$$\left\|x\right\|=\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|x_i\right|^p\right)$$ is a p norm.
I tried 1. and 2. conditon but I can't prove triangle inequality for $p$-norm.
I tried to use minkowski inquality but I can't use it because there is no $(1/p)$ on ther series. I also tried to prove it like this:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|x_i+y_i\right|^p\right)\leq 2^p \left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|x_i\right|^p+|y_i|^p\right)\leq  2^p\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|x_i\right|^p\right)+2^p\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|y_i\right|^p\right)\neq \left\|x\right\|+ \left\|y\right\|$$
but this is not working.
How to prove triangle inequality for this p-norm?

Comment: Can you expand on what values of $p$ you are looking at? Are you looking at $p\in [1, \infty )$ and at $\|x\| := \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{p} \right)^{1/p}$? Or are you looking at $p\in (0, 1)$ with your current definition of $\|x\|$? In the first case you need to adjust your definition, and in the second case you have a metric, but not a norm. In your current situation, the triangle inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: @DeanMiller. here  p∈[1,∞) . I know this is not a norm.I just  tried to prove triangle inequality. by the way  it is $\left\|x\right\|=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|x_i\right|^p\right)$. there is no 1/p in definition.

Comment: Ok. The triangle inequality doesn't hold for $p\in (1, \infty )$. To show this, take $x = y = \frac{1}{2}e_{1}$, where $e_{1}$ is the sequence where the first component is $1$ and the rest are $0$. Then $\|x+y\| = 1$ while $\|x\| + \|y\| = (1/2)^{p} + (1/2)^{p} = (1/2)^{p-1} < 1$. But for $p=1$, the triangle inequality does hold as $\|\cdot\|$ coincides with the $\ell_{1}$ norm.

Comment: @DeanMiller thank you very much.